# How can I fix this python simple recursion problem

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a function that prints the first multiples of a number (n) starting with zero and stopping at num_multiples, but it keeps printing out one too many multiples. I'm hoping someone can explain what I'm doing wrong so I can understand recursion a bit more.

```
def print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples):    
    if num_multiples < 0:
        return
    else:
        print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples - 1)
        print(n * num_multiples, end=' ')
```

for example, passing 5 as n and 10 as num_multiples, it should print:
`0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45`

but is instead printing an extra "50" at the end.

Comment: Why do you think its an extra `50` you print every time num_multiples is greater than 0 and you start it at 10 so it will print 5 * 10 which is 50

Answer (score 1):

First, 0 is not a multiple of 5. The first multiple of 5 is 5 (5*1). The problem with your code is that you only stop when `num_multiples` is negative (less than 0). Instead, you want to stop when it is zero. Like this:

```
def print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples):    
    if num_multiples == 0:
        return
    else:
        print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples - 1)
        print(n * num_multiples, end=' ')


print_first_multiples(5, 10)
```

If you do want to start at 0 and go up to 45, then you can subtract one from `num_multiples`. Like this:

```
def print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples):    
    if num_multiples == 0:
        return
    else:
        print_first_multiples(n, num_multiples - 1)
        print(n * (num_multiples-1), end=' ')


print_first_multiples(5, 10)
```

Comment: 0 is a multiple of 50 (every number) by most definitions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_(mathematics))

Answer (score 0):

Try  if num_multiples <= 0: instead

Comment: That still wouldnt give the expected result the user listed

Answer (score 0):

It prints until it doesn't enter `if num_multiples < 0`. So e.x. with the initial value `num_multiples = 3` you print for `num_multiples=3`, `num_multiples=2`, `num_multiples=1`, and `num_multiples=0` so 4 times. Replace `if num_multiples < 0` with `if num_multiples == 0` and you'd get what you expect